# Transfer token failed due to Gas estimation failed

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, metamask

Have issue transfer token, hope to get support from this. my contract https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x6D96673922d54108e8eFaFDe191Dc473dCeE709B

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;


import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.5.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Capped.sol";
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.5.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.5.0/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";


contract OceanToken is Ownable, ERC20Detailed, ERC20Capped {

    using SafeMath for uint256;

    uint256 CAP = 1410000000;
    uint256 TOTALSUPPLY = CAP.mul(10 ** 18);

    constructor()
        public
        ERC20Detailed('OceanToken', 'OCEAN', 18)
        ERC20Capped(TOTALSUPPLY)
        Ownable()
    {
        _mint(msg.sender, TOTALSUPPLY);
    }

}

contract Try {
  //address token address = 0x8967bcf84170c91b0d24d4302c2376283b0b3a07; // token address
  mapping ( address => uint256 ) public balances;
  
     IERC20 public token;

    constructor(address _token) public {
        token = OceanToken(_token);
    }

  function deposit(uint tokens ) public payable{

    // add the deposited tokens into existing balance 
    balances[msg.sender]+= tokens;

    // transfer the tokens from the sender to this contract
    token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokens);
  }

  function returnTokens() public {
    balances[msg.sender] = 0;
    token.transfer(msg.sender, balances[msg.sender]);
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi, try increasing your GAS Limit before you send .. let me know if it works then!

Comment: And what is the issue you mention ?

Comment: @AvocadoChocolate i do increased the GAS Limit to MAX value but same error show.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain i deployed the contract successfully. The GAS estimation failed when i try to perform deposit action with some token even i adjusted the GAS limit. This happen only when transfer any ERC20 token, for ETHER is fine.

Comment: @ebbsorg The contract calls `transferFrom` from the token, for that to succeed the token owner has to previously approve the contract address. Did the token owner approve Try contract? It should be something like `token.approve(Try.address, amount, { from: tokenOwner })`.